# Using Vidyo Sdk for Javascript, want to show the preview in a specific container instead of given container

Tags: javascript, vidyo

I am using vidyo sdk for web, I have few requirements which i want to implement with vidyo UI,

**1.by default the preview is coming in the right corner but i want show that in the left corner inside a div which i have defined, once the remote person joins the call**

**2. I want to show a test play button, which in turn plays a sound for test purpose is there any default control for that inside vidyo.**

**3. I want to listen to the remote participant microphone mute events i  registered the RegisterRemoteMicrophoneEventListener but it is not firing for the remote microphone changes, i put that after the CreateVidyoConnector then function.**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. By default the preview is coming in the right corner but I want show that in the left corner inside a div which I have defined, once the remote person joins the call

A: You can go with our custom layout option (setting viewID: null).
You will see the sample implementation in our WebSDK sample: https://static.vidyo.io/4.1.22.9/package/VidyoClient-WebSDK.zip
With custom layout, you will have the option to design your own layout/CSS and assign your local preview and remote video into any DIV you desire.

2. I want to show a test play button, which in turn plays a sound for test purpose is there any default control for that inside vidyo.

A: We do not have any API to support this feature. You should implement this at your application level.

3. I want to listen to the remote participant microphone mute events I registered the `RegisterRemoteMicrophoneEventListener` but it is not firing for the remote microphone changes, I put that after the CreateVidyoConnector then function.

A: I tested with the following code snippet:

```
function registerRemoteEventListeners(vidyoConnector) {
    vidyoConnector.RegisterRemoteMicrophoneEventListener({
        onAdded: function (microphone, participant) {
            console.log("RegisterRemoteMicrophoneEventListener onAdded participant.id : " + participant.id);
        },
        onRemoved: function (microphone, participant) {
            console.log("RegisterRemoteMicrophoneEventListener onRemoved participant.id : " + participant.id);
        },
        onStateUpdated: function (microphone, participant, state) {
            // Camera state was updated
            console.log("RegisterRemoteMicrophoneEventListener onStateUpdated participant.id : " + participant.id + " and state: " + state);
        }
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("RegisterRemoteCameraEventListener Success");
    }).catch(function () {
        console.error("RegisterRemoteCameraEventListener Failed");
    });
}
```

I will received output in console like the following when other participant mute/unmute their microphone:

```
onStateUpdated participant.id : 069b1adcca520910 and state: VIDYO_DEVICESTATE_Paused
onStateUpdated participant.id : 069b1adcca520910 and state: VIDYO_DEVICESTATE_Resumed
```